# Objects and Reference Count | Java

Tags: java, object, reference

Consider the following code snippet in Java:

```
Customer obj1 = new  Customer();  
Customer obj2 = new Customer();  
Customer obj3 = obj2;  
obj3 = obj1;
```

How many reference variables and objects are created here?
 The solutions I came across were all confusing. Please explain.

Comment: What solution you came across? And what you are confused with? What is `custObj2` there?

Comment: @millimoose Yeah, explaining it from that angle might make things more confusing for him/her though.

Comment: Here's a little puzzle. How many professional programmers does it take to write `2`? The answer is below :)

Comment: @millimoose Of course there are references. It is even defined [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1): *The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.*

Comment: @assylias Thanks for that, I guess I had the C++-ism on my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Customer Obj1= new  Customer();
```

// Customer object is created on the heap and obj1 refers it

```
Customer Obj2= new Customer();
```

//Customer object is created on the heap and obj2 refers it

```
Customer Obj3= Obj2;
```

// obj3 will refer to customer object created by obj2

```
 Obj3= Obj1;
```

// obj3 (previosly refering to cust obj craeted by obj2 will be lost) and will now refer to cust obj created by obj1

Thus i would say **2 objects and 3 ref variables**

- obj1 and obj3 refering to Object created by obj1
- obj2 refers to Object created by obj2 itself

Answer (score 3):

After

```
Obj3= Obj1;
```

You'll have two objects and 3 references. Obj1 and Obj3 will reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Although the JLS doesn't forbid it, AFAIK no JVM uses reference counting, it is just too unreliable. Note: C++ smart pointer uses references counts but these are very inefficient.

You have up to three references to two different objects.

Note: unless your code does something useful with them the JVM can optimise this code away to nothing, in which case you will have no references or objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `custObj2` is initialized with `new`,
and from the above snippet, its 3 objects (including `custObj2`) and four references( including `Obj3`)

Answer (score 0):

There are three variables and two objects created.

Answer (score 0):

2 objects are created (the first 2 lines).

There are 3 reference variables created (Obj1, Obj2, and Obj3 are all reference variables.)

The last 2 lines simply assign references to 2 different objects to Obj3.

Answer (score 0):

Step through it iteratively...

```
Customer Obj1= new  Customer();
```

One new object created, referenced by Obj1

```
Customer Obj2= new Customer();
```

A second object created, referenced by Obj2

```
Customer Obj3= custObj2;
```

Obj3, a reference variable, refers to `custObj2` (which doesn't exist in this set of data, we'll assume it was created earlier?)

```
Obj3= Obj1;
```

Obj3 is re-assigned to point at Obj1.

In the end you have the three references, Obj1, Obj2, and Obj3 as well as 2 objects, (first two statements) and finally an ambiguous `custObj2`... if you meant to type Obj2 then ignore that part :)